# Leer fecha de un fichero

Tags: c++

Quiero leer una fecha de un fichero de la siguiente forma:

por ejemplo

```
void Store::leerUsuarios(const string &nombreFichero){
 ifstream fichero;
 fichero.open(nombreFichero);
 if (fichero.is_open()) {
    string nom, mail;
    int dia; int mes; int anyo;


    while ((fichero >> nombre) && (fichero >> mail) && (fichero >> dia) && 
    (fichero >> mes) && (fichero >> anyo)) {
        fichero >> nombre;
        fichero >> mail;
        fichero >> dia;
        fichero >> mes;
        fichero >> anyo;
         }
    fichero.close();
     }
 }
```

con fstream en un fichero lo va separando por espacios, pero si tengo una fecha por ejemplo:

```
01/01/2000
```

¿Cómo hago para que me pueda leer eso?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. El código que has puesto lee de un fichero, luego entiendo que sabes leer su contenido... ¿qué problema tiene la fecha que comentas?

Comment: ¿En qué sistema operativo? ¿Puedes usar C++17?

Comment: @eferion a los que me refiero es que quiero leer el dia, mes y año por separado,(lo he puesto en string ha sido un error) y quiero que los "/" funcionen como si fuera " "

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para reflejar ese requisito

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus en windows 10 visual studio 2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si asumimos que la fecha va a estar bien escrita, la lectura puede quedar bastante sencilla:

```
ifstream fichero;
// abre el fichero..

int dia, int mes, int anio;
fichero >> dia;
fichero.ignore(); // Descartamos la primera barra
fichero >> mes;
fichero.ignore(); // Descartamos la segunda barra
fichero >> anio;
```

Podemos ahorrarnos el `ignore` si usamos una variable tipo `char`:

```
int dia, int mes, int anio;
char separador;

fichero >> dia >> separador >> mes >> separador >> anio;
```